# Tools for changing hydraulic hoses on Deutz 6250

Tags: tools, hose, hydraulic-pressure

I have a problem with the hydraulic coupling on the auxiliary hydraulics on my tractor.

There are 4 lines that connect in a very small area.  The required 26 mm 1 1/16" wrench can't turn the coupling the required 1/12 of a turn to get it far enough to grab with the wrench flipped over.

What ways are there to get at difficult locations?

- Clearance doesn't allow for a crowsfoot.
- I can get small waterpump pliers in there, but can't get enough leverage.
- I don't think there is enough diameter difference between fitting and hose to use a flare nut wrench.

Answer (score 1):

Without a picture, the only thing I can suggest is that on hydraulic blocks we would work from the inside ones to the outside ones...

This means, that if an inner one is leaking, you need to remove one or more outer ones and sort/tighten the inner one then refit the outer ones...

Comment: I may have to do that.  Seems like poor design. Sigh.

Comment: Design also means fitting into X amount of space - while your application may have plenty of room, other applications may not... But good luck with it anyway.